# Dont save webform data to database

Tags: 7, database

For SPECIFIC webforms, how can I make it not save data to the database, but just send the email? It should however still save the files and link to them in the email.

Idk if I can use something like this: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_clear since this seems to work on all webforms, while I wanna use it only on specific ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What files are you referring to?

If there are files being generated from webform node content then the data probably has to be saved first in order to generate the files. In this case you should target to delete the nodes once the email has been sent (while allowing for them to be created at first). You can look into Rules module for that.

Webforms all have separate email settings so I'd expect the webform_clear to also offer per-form settings.